# Using Facebook's Open Graph to retrieve friends "user/friends"

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am struggling to find a solution to this issue. I am aware of Facebook Graph 2.0+ disabled the query of all Facebook friends. You can only return friends that are using the same app. When I try to use the Facebook's Graph API to return the friends that are using the same app, I am only returned the amount of friends a user has like so:

```
{
   "data": [   
   ],
   "summary": {
   "total_count": 1206
   }
}
```

It displays the total number of friends, however its not returning any names of the people. All users are giving the **user_friends** permission. I am testing out the graph API with two Facebook accounts that are subscribed to the same app, and I double checked their "apps" page on Facebook accounts and they both have the attributes within the apps permissions **user_friends**.

The Graph URL im using is like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USERS ID/friends?access_token=ACCESS TOKEN
```

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT: I fixed the issue. You should use this API call instead.**

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=ACCESS TOKEN
```

Comment: I fixed it. https://graph.facebook.com/USERS ID/friends?access_token=ACCESS TOKEN actually needs to be https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=ACCESS TOKEN. Change the users id to "me" and it works.

Comment: That only means that your access token was not for that user id. (If it was, then it would make no difference whether you used the user id or `/me`.)